qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "offscreen" in ""
I'm trying to run a python script in a conda environment. Im using a ubuntu(Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS) machine through SSH. I'm running colmap on a dataset and getting the following error:
==== running: colmap feature_extractor                 --database_path data/N3V/coffee_martini/tmp/database.db                 --image_path data/N3V/coffee_martini/tmp/images
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms" ...
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "offscreen" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

*** Aborted at 1718876096 (unix time) try "date -d @1718876096" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @                0x0 (unknown)
*** SIGABRT (@0x3e80018404b) received by PID 1589323 (TID 0x7f14e59ebf80) from PID 1589323; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f14eb0d7197 google::(anonymous namespace)::FailureSignalHandler()
    @     0x7f14e9802420 (unknown)
    @     0x7f14e914800b gsignal
    @     0x7f14e9127859 abort
    @     0x7f14e98a135b QMessageLogger::fatal()
    @     0x7f14e9d5f799 QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration()
    @     0x7f14e9d5fb6f QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher()
    @     0x7f14e99beb62 QCoreApplicationPrivate::init()
    @     0x7f14e9d601e1 QGuiApplicationPrivate::init()
    @     0x7f14ea1e6bc5 QApplicationPrivate::init()
    @     0x55bbce67b975 colmap::RunFeatureExtractor()
    @     0x55bbce6641a0 main
    @     0x7f14e9129083 __libc_start_main
    @     0x55bbce667e39 (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
FATAL: command failed

The packages installed in conda env are following:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                  2_kmp_llvm    conda-forge
addict                    2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ansi2html                 1.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
antlr4-python3-runtime    4.9.3                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     23.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl
boost-cpp                 1.74.0               h312852a_4    conda-forge
brotli-python             1.0.9            py37hd23a5d3_7    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7f98852_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2024.6.2             hbcca054_0    conda-forge
ceres-solver              2.1.0                h2ea6fbf_2    conda-forge
certifi                   2024.6.2           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
colmap                    3.7                  h06efa00_2    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
comm                      0.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
configargparse            1.7                      pypi_0    pypi
cudatoolkit               11.6.2              hfc3e2af_12    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
dash                      2.14.2                   pypi_0    pypi
dash-core-components      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
dash-html-components      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
dash-table                5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
dbus                      1.13.6               h48d8840_2    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
diff-gaussian-rasterization 0.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
eigen                     3.4.0                h00ab1b0_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.6.2                h59595ed_0    conda-forge
fastjsonschema            2.19.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ffmpeg                    4.3                  hf484d3e_0    pytorch
flann                     1.9.1             h848e4f1_1007    conda-forge
flask                     2.2.5                    pypi_0    pypi
fontconfig                2.14.2               h14ed4e7_0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.38.0                   pypi_0    pypi
freeimage                 3.18.0              h530e30e_10    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               h267a509_2    conda-forge
gettext                   0.22.5               h59595ed_2    conda-forge
gettext-tools             0.22.5               h59595ed_2    conda-forge
gflags                    2.2.2             he1b5a44_1004    conda-forge
glew                      2.1.0                h9c3ff4c_2    conda-forge
glib                      2.68.4               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.68.4               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
glog                      0.6.0                h6f12383_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.2.1                h58526e2_0    conda-forge
gnutls                    3.6.13               h85f3911_1    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.18.4               h29181c9_0    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.18.5               h76c114f_0    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.5          nompi_h5b725eb_1114    conda-forge
icu                       68.2                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
imagesize                 1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
imath                     3.1.6                h6239696_1    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        6.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-resources       5.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   7.34.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipywidgets                8.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
itsdangerous              2.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.19.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    3.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9e                   h0b41bf4_3    conda-forge
jsonschema                4.17.3                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-widgets        3.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
jxrlib                    1.1                  hd590300_3    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
kornia                    0.6.12                   pypi_0    pypi
krb5                      1.19.3               h3790be6_0    conda-forge
lame                      3.100             h166bdaf_1003    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.14                 h6ed2654_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.40                 h41732ed_0    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libasprintf               0.22.5               h661eb56_2    conda-forge
libasprintf-devel         0.22.5               h661eb56_2    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0            12_linux64_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0            12_linux64_mkl    conda-forge
libclang                  11.1.0          default_ha53f305_1    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.14                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.10               h9b69904_4    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.6.2                h59595ed_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h58526e2_2    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 13.2.0               h807b86a_2    conda-forge
libgettextpo              0.22.5               h59595ed_2    conda-forge
libgettextpo-devel        0.22.5               h59595ed_2    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            13.2.0               h69a702a_8    conda-forge
libgfortran5              13.2.0               h3d2ce59_8    conda-forge
libglib                   2.68.4               h3e27bee_0    conda-forge
libglu                    9.0.0             he1b5a44_1001    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0            12_linux64_mkl    conda-forge
libllvm11                 11.1.0               he0ac6c6_5    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h753d276_0    conda-forge
libpq                     13.8                 hd77ab85_0    conda-forge
libraw                    0.20.2               h9772cbc_2    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.43.2               h2797004_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              13.2.0               h7e041cc_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.4.0                h82bc61c_5    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.2                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h7f98852_1004    conda-forge
libxkbcommon              1.0.3                he3ba5ed_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.12               h72842e0_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               17.0.2               h4dfa4b3_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
metis                     5.1.0             h59595ed_1007    conda-forge
mkl                       2021.4.0           h8d4b97c_729    conda-forge
mkl-service               2.4.0            py37h402132d_0    conda-forge
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py37h3e078e5_1    conda-forge
mkl_random                1.2.2            py37h219a48f_0    conda-forge
mpfr                      4.2.1                h9458935_0    conda-forge
mysql-common              8.0.32               h14678bc_0    conda-forge
mysql-libs                8.0.32               h54cf53e_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.4                  hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.8                    pypi_0    pypi
nettle                    3.6                  he412f7d_0    conda-forge
nspr                      4.35                 h27087fc_0    conda-forge
nss                       3.94                 h1d7d5a4_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.21.5           py37h6c91a56_3
numpy-base                1.21.5           py37ha15fc14_3
omegaconf                 2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
open3d                    0.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.9.0.80                 pypi_0    pypi
openexr                   3.1.5                h0cdce71_2    conda-forge
openh264                  2.1.1                h780b84a_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.5.0                h7d73246_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1w               hd590300_0    conda-forge
packaging                 23.2                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    1.3.5                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pcre                      8.45                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    9.2.0            py37h850a105_2    conda-forge
pip                       22.3.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10                   pypi_0    pypi
plotly                    5.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
plyfile                   0.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pointops2                 1.0                      pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.43                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
py-cpuinfo                9.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.17.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyquaternion              0.9.9                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.19.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1            py37h89c1867_5    conda-forge
python                    3.7.13               haa1d7c7_1
python-dateutil           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python_abi                3.7                     2_cp37m    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.12.1          py3.7_cuda11.6_cudnn8.3.2_0    pytorch
pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
pytz                      2023.3.post1             pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
qt                        5.12.9               hda022c4_4    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h8228510_1    conda-forge
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
retrying                  1.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
seaborn                   0.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                68.2.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
simple-knn                0.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.43.2               h2c6b66d_0    conda-forge
suitesparse               5.10.1               h9e50725_1    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.7.0             h924138e_0    conda-forge
tenacity                  8.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.13               h2797004_0    conda-forge
torchaudio                0.12.1               py37_cu116    pytorch
torchmetrics              0.11.4                   pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.13.1               py37_cu116    pytorch
tqdm                      4.66.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
typing_extensions         4.7.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
ultralytics               8.0.145                  pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   2.0.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
vlfeat                    0.9.21               hd590300_1    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.12                   pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  2.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.41.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        4.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
xorg-fixesproto           5.0               h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.1.1                hd590300_0    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.4                h7391055_0    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.8.4                h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.11               hd590300_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.4                h0b41bf4_2    conda-forge
xorg-libxfixes            5.0.3             h7f98852_1004    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.10            h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1            h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0             h0b41bf4_1003    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31            h7f98852_1007    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.5                hfc55251_0    conda-forge

I have tried multiple solution such as setting export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
and installing packages like libxcb-xinerama0, libxcb-cursor0.
None of them works.
Update :
I tried with DEBUG mode and copied the platforms directory to bin directory got the following error:
ffmpeg version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (crosstool-NG 1.23.0.449-a04d0)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/conda/conda-bld/ffmpeg_1597178665428/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeh --cc=/opt/conda/conda-bld/ffmpeg_1597178665428/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc --disable-doc --disable-openssl --enable-avresample --enable-gnutls --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenh264 --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-version3 --enable-zlib --enable-libmp3lame
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'data/N3V/coffee_martini/cam08.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 53819 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 2704x2028 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 53815 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to 'data/N3V/coffee_martini/images//cam08_%04d.png':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: png, rgb24, 2704x2028 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 png
frame=  300 fps= 69 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=N/A speed=2.31x
video:1987329kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[INFO] loaded 5400 images from 18 videos, 18 poses_bounds as (18, 17)
[INFO] H = 2028.0, W = 2704.0, fl = 1460.7543404163334
[INFO] totp = [-10.07408828   1.63833876   0.12084504]
[INFO] average radius = 10.74049884871234
[INFO] write to data/N3V/coffee_martini/transforms_train.json and data/N3V/coffee_martini/transforms_test.json
==== running: colmap feature_extractor                 --database_path data/N3V/coffee_martini/tmp/database.db                 --image_path data/N3V/coffee_martini/tmp/images
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqwebgl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqwebgl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webgl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebGLIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webgl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330752
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
loaded library "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, webgl, xcb.

*** Aborted at 1718954829 (unix time) try "date -d @1718954829" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @                0x0 (unknown)
*** SIGABRT (@0x3e800193498) received by PID 1651864 (TID 0x7ffa9853bf80) from PID 1651864; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7ffa9dc27197 google::(anonymous namespace)::FailureSignalHandler()
    @     0x7ffa9c352420 (unknown)
    @     0x7ffa9bc9800b gsignal
    @     0x7ffa9bc77859 abort
    @     0x7ffa9c3f135b QMessageLogger::fatal()
    @     0x7ffa9c8af799 QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration()
    @     0x7ffa9c8afb6f QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher()
    @     0x7ffa9c50eb62 QCoreApplicationPrivate::init()
    @     0x7ffa9c8b01e1 QGuiApplicationPrivate::init()
    @     0x7ffa9cd36bc5 QApplicationPrivate::init()
    @     0x55de6ecf7975 colmap::RunFeatureExtractor()
    @     0x55de6ece01a0 main
    @     0x7ffa9bc79083 __libc_start_main
    @     0x55de6ece3e39 (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
FATAL: command failed


Does this answer your question? Ubuntu 22.04 & Qt 6.5 : qt.qpa.plugin Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Could you post the output when "QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS = 1" is set?

I am using a remote server through SSH and Dont know how to set the QT_DEBUG_PLUGIN=1. I think the actual problem is here.
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms"
There is no file or directory named platforms in my bin folder.

Call export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 before starting your program.

I guess for your output in debug mode, export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen was not set.

@m7913d
I set the QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen and the error is now this :
loaded library "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/platformthemes" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/gaussian_splatting/bin/styles" ...
This plugin does not support createPlatformOpenGLContext!
F20240621 16:48:55.162644 1661532 opengl_utils.cc:56] Check failed: context_.create()

It seems to me that you/colmap tries to show a GUI, which isn't supported by the offscreen plugin. Can your run colmap without GUI? Note however that I'm not familiar with conda nor colmap. It also looks strange to me that you had to manually copy the platforms folder.

@m7913d I think you are right about colmap GUI. But I dont know how to disable diplay. On option is to set the GUI_ENABLED as false during the build of colmap but I dont know how to do that  as Im working in a conda environment and installed colmap using "conda install colmap".
